# Searching/fitering from a firestore data listview, flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, search, filtering, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a searchbar on a listview activity, the listview contains two texts (names and twitter username). Given there are hundreds of people on that listview, please how do I search by name using Flutter?

What I've done

```dart
void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List<String> dummySearchList = List<String>();
    dummySearchList.addAll(listItems);
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<String> dummyListData = List<String>();
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
        if (item.contains(query)) {
          dummyListData.add(item);        }
      });
      setState(() {
        writeSearch.clear();
        writeSearch.addAll(dummyListData);
      });      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        writeSearch.clear();
        writeSearch.addAll(listItems);
      });
    }
  }
```

But the listItems gives error

The below is my Firestore call

```dart
BatchBStreamOneNotifier batchBStreamOneNotifier = Provider.of<BatchBStreamOneNotifier>(context, listen: false);
getBatchBStreamOne(batchBStreamOneNotifier);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to search the list that already populated to the `listview` or you want to search `firestore` directly?

Comment: Hello, @JideGuru Thanks for the response. Yes, I want to search from the list that is already populated to the listview. Not from firestore.

Comment: Okay. I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

This should help you search the list:

```dart
 List originalItemList = List();
  List searchedItemList = List();
  search(String query){
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {

      // search the list for the user `name`
      List nameSearch = originalItemList.where((user){
        String userName = user['name'];
        return userName.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
      }).toList();

      // set the filtered list to the unfiltered list
      setState(() {
        searchedItemList = nameSearch;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        searchedItemList = originalItemList;
      });
    }
  }
```